# JavaScript check if wanted url is in window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the current address is https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/de/cart/view.
The problem is that the de is the country code and it will change if you access from another IP.

In the .json manifest you could set it up with https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/*/cart/view but that won't work in JS.

My code

```
if (window.location.href  === 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/*/cart/view') {
    alert("AAAA")
}
```

How should I replace the * so all countrycodes would work when checking?
Thanks

Comment: You should look into creating a regex, and check for a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be comparing all parts of the two urls except the country code:

```js
let url1 = 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/ge/cart/view';
let url2 = 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/de/cart/view';
console.log(compareUrls(url1.split('/'), url2.split('/')));
url2 = 'https://www.sneakersnstuff1.com/de/cart/view';
console.log(compareUrls(url1.split('/'), url2.split('/')));

function compareUrls(a, b){
     var i = a.length;
     if (i != b.length) 
          return false;
     while (i--)
          if (a[i] !== b[i] && i != 3) 
               return false;
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your use case, but maybe you could check in a different way, for example:

```
window.location.href.includes('/cart/view');
```

Or if you need to check the whole url you could split them and then exclude from the array the localization part of the url.

Comment: Thanks for that easy solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 here like this:

```
if (window.location.href === `https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/${country_code}/cart/view`) {
     alert("AAAA")
}
```